# Finding all dates between a range in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a sas dataset of some dates. I need to generate all dates from 01FEB2008 to 31AUG2009. How do i go about this? Also then i need to find all the missing dates from another column of dates. Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please put your sample code too..

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more concise version of Honh Ooi's code...

```
data alldates ;
  do dt = '01feb2008'd to '31aug2009'd ;
    output ;
  end ;
  format dt date9. ;
run ;

proc sql ;
  create table dtmiss as
  select * from alldates
  where dt not in(select dt from mydata) ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
data dates (keep=dte);
  start = '01feb2008'd;
  end = '31aug2009'd;
  len = end - start;
  format dte date9.;
  do i = 0 to len;
    dte = start + i;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

To find the missing dates:

```
data test;
  merge dates (in=a) mydata (in=b);
  by dte;
  if a and not b;
run;
```